# For how long an app in background would keep receiving bluetooth packets?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth

I'm researching for a PoC that users would have a mobile app (Android and iOS) connected to a Bluetooth device. Users would lock their cellphone, put them away (close enough for keeping the Bluetooth connection) then the mobile app would stream (broadcast the Bluetooth packets) to an HTTP endpoint.

The mobile app would behave like a hub broadcasting Bluetooth packets.

The stream should last for about 1 - 2 hours.

Would that work or Android and iOS eventually terminate the app?

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, it seems like if you enable Bluetooth-LE related background modes [1], you should be able to "handle important central role events, such as when a connection is established or torn down, when a peripheral sends updated characteristic values, and when a central manager’s state changes.". The caveat to this is that once woken up, you only have a short amount of time (approximately 10 seconds) to perform some processing like sending an HTTP request.

[1] https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html